# Chat application in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I want to implement chat application in SharePoint 2013.
I need the Steps for Development and my requirement is that users should able to chat with each other

How can I achieve this scenario?

Comment: Have a look at it https://sharepointchat.codeplex.com/

Comment: I like to use the comment function (social feed), it's built in SharePoint and you can use the comment function by itself or with anything such as news, pictures, or documents.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft created a chat app for SharePoint. it's called [Teams](https://teamsdemo.office.com)

You can create topics and teams in there so you can chat with different groups of people inside Teams!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/90403)

Comment: I tried previous answers and this was my answer.. I can exit it though!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of 3rd party app / web parts available if you want to use them.

[A chat tool for SharePoint 2013](https://blog.riolinx.com/2014/02/12/a-chat-tool-for-sharepoint-2013/)

[Lightning Chat](https://store.office.com/lightning-chat-WA103524905.aspx?assetid=WA103524905)

also check this one, may work for you: [Chat in SharePoint – The Easy Way (No Code)](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2012/07/20/chat-in-sharepoint-the-easy-way-no-code-aspx/)

Comment: No Code solution is really a trick. We can even customize the list view and use it as a chat screen.. Great..!!

Comment: There is a reason why people insist that do not just post links and instead explain the answer. Now see what happened....that no code chat in SharePoint link is dead!! It looked very interesting to me as I am looking for some chat solution but the link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Another nice [SharePoint Chat](https://www.goodpointsoftware.com/sp/apps/chat.html).
Or from Microsoft Office Store as Add-In: [SharePoint Chat](https://store.office.com/goodpoint-chat-pro-WA104379649.aspx?assetid=WA104379649)